# Multiple insertions (<<) vs concatenating output (+)

Tags: c++, output, operators, ostream

I'm wondering what the difference would be between doing, for example,

```cpp
void example1(ostream &out, string &name, string &title, int years) {
    out << "Hello, my name is " << name << " and I have been working as a "
        << title << " for " << years << " years.\n";
}
```

and,

```cpp
void example2(ostream &out, string &name, string &title, int years) {
    out << "Hello, my name is " + name + " and I have been working as a "
        + title + " for " + to_string(years) + " years.\n";
    }
```

The example1 calls the insertion operator several times, whereas example2 calls the insertion operator only once after concatenating all the strings. Is one safer or more performant than the other? Does the same concerns that apply to `cout` in regards to this also apply to other output streams such as `ostringstream`?

In other words, is it faster and/or more reliable to output string data individually using `<<` as in example1, or to concatenate everything before sending it to output as in example 2?

Here's a compiling *"fiddle"* of my example code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MPetxq

Comment: What are the types of `years` and `name` in the example you are thinking of? Consider making a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch, I was thinking in the sense of strings, but I realize `years` could be stored as a numeric data type. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok. Please let me know whether my answer is close to your new way of thinking, or what is missing. I'd happily get closer to your problem... ;-)

Comment: What is the stream state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version only requires overloading `<<` for each of the involved types.
The second one requires overloading `+` for each occurring pair of involved types and also requires creating an object of the result type which can then be output. Admittedly, `<<` only needs to be overloaded for that resulting type.

Depending on how complex the overloads and especially the creation of the result type object are, these differences can have an effect on speed.
For optimisation purposes, it is always necessary to do measuring instead of guessing. But I think I'd bet on not having to create objects for speed and not having to do multiple overloads for simplicity.

Comment: That is a very good point when it comes to using custom datatypes or templates that require the programmer to overload those operators, so I upvoted you for that. :) My question, however, is more about whether is it faster or slower to concatenate strings (and basic types such as `int`) before sending it to an output stream (such as `cout` or `ostringstream`'s). I updated my question so that hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: I added some discussion of the speed effect of the differences. Probably a bit disappointing, because there is not general answer, but maybe I got a little closer.